# What is a shear release?

Tags: statics, beam

For my statics project, we are being asked to draw the shear and bending moment diagram for a beam, which is usually pretty straightforward. However, here there is something called a shear release on the diagram, which we never talked about. Our professor said to just google it, but I couldn't really find anything exact (I'm probably just searching for the wrong thing).

My understanding is that the shear release just makes the shear at that point go to zero and "resets" it, if you will. Is that correct? A few places mentioned something about transferring it to a moment, but I'm not sure what they meant or if they were even talking about the same thing.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the diagram?

Answer (score 1):

(This is more like a comment, because I think you need to add more details on the exact problem you have.)

To my understanding a *shear release joint* would be something like the following :

[image]

**figure: (source: [uiuc.edu](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/education/calc-init/static-beam/support.html))**

Essentially the shear release joint is  a joint that constraints

- axial translational  movement
- rotational movement (so it allows bending moments and torque moments to be non zero through it)

but can be "released" (for lack of a better word) with a shear force.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a support or joint which can have x, y, z reactions and moments but not any shear reaction. it is vertically free to play.

they usally show it by two vertical parallel lines. like this, -----------|| .

Answer (score 0):

It is a "guided support", in which the beam can deflect vertically but rotation is prohibited by clamping. The guided support can't resist shear force; it is most often seen in piping engineering.

[image]